# Java: Constructor of a subclass has an Object of parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm learning Java at school and I have encountered a problem with inheritance and constructors.
I have 3 classes, Class A, Class B and Class C.
Class A is the superclass, Class B extends class A and Class C extends Class B.
Class B has a constructor whose formal(parameter) is a String. All good till here.
So now, I extend Class B to Class C. In Class C I need to create a constructor that
has an instance of Class B as its parameter. I then need to extract some information
from Class B and store that in Class C.

Here is the code we have.

```
public class B extends A {

int b;

public B(int b) {
this.b=b;
}

}

public class C extends B {

int c;

public C(B b) {

this.c = b.b;

}

}
```

In my main()

I have the following line of code to create an instance of C

C c_c = new C(new B(12));

When this is compiled, I get an error.
error: constructor B in class B cannot be applied to given types;

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Would you guys be able to help me understand what I've done wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to recompile the other class files.

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly call B's constructor from C's constructor since no default constructor defined in class B

```
public C(B b) {
   super(0);
   this.c = b.b;
}
```

Comment: Or, more likely, `super(b.b);`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to reload information from B to C. Simply make B's fields visible to C eg make them protected